# How to ignore battery charging notification

Tags: android

I managed to create a service to wake the screen on android 13, but when phone is charging the screen keeps turning on. I used the next code to ignore notifications while charging I'm a beginner in this and I'm asking if there is a better way to do this.

```
String packageName = sbn.getPackageName();
     if(packageName == null ||
        packageName.equals("com.android.systemui")
     ){return;}
```

Comment: Why do you need a service to wake the screen?  That's unlikely to work well.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: this is totally for my private use, on my android phone when I get a notification from WhatsApp and many other Apps I just hear the alert tone and the screen stays off, so I made this app just to wake the screen up. I didn't like the idea of accessing my notifications from other apps at google play or anywhere else.

Comment: The reason a service won't work well is that they're killed when they get backgrounded for more than 2 minutes.  They aren't reliable on stock Android.  A foreground service is more reliable, but can still be killed.  Personally I hate it when my phone comes on randomly, but there generally is a setting to do that I think

Comment: Thank you, until now it works as I need.